# Flash CS6 AS3: Audio is playing from previous frames when using gotoAndStop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, flash-cs6

When I'm using MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop() to navigate to another frame. The audio in the movieclips from the frames between will start playing. The audio is set to "STREAM" in all movieclips and there is no additional code to start the movieclips. I have placed traces in the movieclips to notify me when the audio movieclips start and finish their frame sequence.

Say if I am on frame 1 of the main scene and I use "GotoAndStop(4)", the audio from frame 2 and 3 and 4 start playing.

I have no idea why, or if this is a bug or something to do with the audio settings. Anyone help?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Well it's spread over a lot of movieclips and layers, it would be very difficult to paste the code on here. But the setup is simply just main_scene with frames which have movieclips of around 200 frames with Streaming audio and a frame at the beginning with a trace and at the end with a stop() and trace() function.

Comment: This question is not about programming, is about using the Flash IDE...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my project.

I solved it by putting:

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;

SoundMixer.stopAll();
```

on the beginning of the movieclips in each frame.

Comment: That works for when the frame is entered. But after around 15 seconds, the audio starts.